# displaying a value with where not in clause in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this table structure
1. Appointments table

```
Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
...
$table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('schedule_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->string('sesi_id')->nullable();
...
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
$table->foreign('schedule_id')->references('id')->on('schedules');
});
```

2. Schedules table

```
Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
...
$table->integer('consultant_id')->unsigned();
$table->string('sesi_id');
$table->date('date');
...
$table->foreign('consultant_id')->references('id')->on('consultants')->onDelete('cascade'); 
});
```

I've tried something like this:

> note: $coba1 is just example, what i want is where date not id

```
$schedules=Schedule::with('sesi')->where([['tanggal', $tanggal], ['office_id', $req->office], ['consultant_id', $req->consul]])->first();
$coba1=Appointment::where('id', 1)->first();
$coba=Schedule::whereNotIn(explode(',', $schedules->sesi_id), Appointment::where('id', 1)->pluck(explode(',', $coba1->sesi_id))->toArray())->dd();
```

I want to display Schedules column sesi_id `WHERE NOT IN` table appointment where `date = $req-date` .

the problem is:

1. in table appointment doesn't have a date column, but it has schedule_id that has date column in it.
2. column sesi_id is multiple value, result of implode so the format is string

Comment: `->pluck(explode(',', $coba1->sesi_id))->toArray())->dd()` this is a big mess. what's inside `sesi_id`, list of column ?

Comment: thanks for the response, sesi_id contains table sesi with multiple value of id sesi. ex:`1,3,4,2,5`

Comment: in `whereIn()` and `whereNotIn()` methods, the first parameter is the column, and the second is an array of values. Why are you giving it an array of `id` as first parameter ? same thing for the `pluck()` method, the parameter is a column name.

Comment: yes i know that before, but as i said the problem is the column of sesi_id is multiple values of id sesi, I'm trying to explode first the sesi_id